# How to define custom exception printers using Janestreet Core?

Tags: ocaml

By default, a `Failure` exception is printed as such:

```
# print_endline (Printexc.to_string (Failure "uh\noh"));;
Failure("uh\noh")
```

For improved readability, we want to print the argument of `Failure` as is because we understand it should be human-readable. In the OCaml standard library, we would initialize an application with the following:

```
# Printexc.register_printer (function
  | Failure s -> Some ("Failure: " ^ s)
  | _ -> None
);;
```

The new behavior of `Printexc.to_string` would be:

```
# print_endline (Printexc.to_string (Failure "uh\noh"));;
Failure: uh
oh
```

Great. Now if we use the core_kernel library, first we can see that printing an exception is slightly different but not better to a human reader:

```
#require "core_kernel";;
# print_endline (Printexc.to_string (Failure "uh\noh"));;
(Failure  "uh\
         \noh")
```

Perhaps we can override this? Let's try.

```
# Printexc.register_printer (function
  | Failure s -> Some ("Failure: " ^ s)
  | _ -> None
);;
# print_endline (Printexc.to_string (Failure "uh\noh"));;
Failure: uh
oh
```

This works, but it's not using the printer that's part of `Core_kernel`. If we use it, we still get the same unreadable result:

```
# print_endline (Core_kernel.Exn.to_string (Failure "uh\noh"));;
(Failure  "uh\
         \noh")
```

And `Core_kernel.Exn` doesn't offer a `register_printer` function. So effectively, it looks like `Core_kernel.Exn` makes sure that we don't define custom exception printers. Is there another way or should we just not use `Core_kernel.Exn` then if we want to show human-readable error messages?

Edit: For context, our original problem is to print nested error messages nicely. For example, we would like to read something like the following:

```
Uncaught exception: Failure:
  Uncaught exception in subprocess 1234: Failure:
    something happened
    trace line 1
    trace line 2
  trace line 1
  trace line 2
  trace line 3
```

where we use indentation for quoting and escaping, rather than double-quotes and backslash escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

`Base.Exn` (for which `Core_kernel.Exn` is an alias) prints errors as human readable s-expressions using Sexplib0 printer and converters. It is possible to add custom sexp converter for exceptions with `Sexplib0.Exn_converter.add`.

However, if you don't intend to print exceptions as s-expressions, I see indeed no reason to use the printer of `Base.Exn`.

EDIT: Since the problem seems to be the printing of S-expressions, one solution might be to use Base.Exn.sexp_of and then plug-in a custom S-expression printers that does not escape strings, nor print parenthesis:

```
let pp_sep ppf () = Format.fprintf ppf "@ "
let pp_sexp ppf = function
  | Atom s -> Format.pp_print_string ppf s
  | List l ->
    Format.fprintf ppf "@[<v 2>  %a@]" 
      (Format.pp_print_list ~pp_sep pp_sexp) l

let to_string exn = Format.asprintf "%a" pp_sexp (Exn.sexp_of_t exn)
```

Comment: I see. S-expressions unfortunately are no longer very human-readable as soon as there are nested exceptions e.g. `to_string (Failure (to_string e))`. Adding this as an example.